# Why circulator on heatpump Armstrong S-25 BF Cast Iron In-Line Pump, 1/12 hp breaks every year?

Tags: heating

I have a 4 zone water based heating system. One S-25 BF Cast Iron In-Line Pump, 1/12 hp heat pump for all 4 zones. The spring circulator breaks every year. It just broken again eventhough the assembly does not require any lubrication on S-25 BF. Before this model I had S-25 which required lubrication and I could see that on those old pumps lubricant oil was causing issue so I bought this one. Now it broke again.

Why is spring ciculator breaking every year?

Is there heatpump w/o circualtor that I can use in place of S-25 BF. Do I need a more powerful pump?

Comment: FYI; A circulator is not a "heatpump" even though it is a pump used on a heating system. A heatpump is a completely different heating system.

Comment: You  said that you replaced the pump. What exactly did you replace? Did you replace the complete pump, including motor or just the pump assembly or just the bearing assembly?

Comment: By the way, an Armstrong S-25 is not a maintenance free pump. It still needs lubricated.

Comment: What is the water  pressure on the boiler?

Comment: Thanks for responding.
1. I replaced it with new pump. Most recently was sent directly from Armstrong as the last one broke.

Comment: 2. It has two models. one is maintenane free and older one is not.
   From the manual, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3tJmysSYpbCTlY5SkR4LVdjS0U/view
   "4 Maintenance free S&H circulators are identified by ‘mf’ in their item numbers"
   Installed model is 174031MF-013 (http://www.supplyhouse.com/Armstrong-Pumps-174031MF-013-S-25-BF-Cast-Iron-In-Line-Pump-1-12-hp)
   Before I was using 174031-013 and lubricating every season, https://www.johnstonesupply.com/storefront/product-view.ep?pID=L86-249

Comment: 3. The needle on the guage from Boiler is at 20 psi and 180 F

For last two days it's getting colder and pump is getting a bit loude.  tomorrw we have big snow storm and moment of truth to see if the pump can survive through it :-)

BTW, I am not sure if you read my comments from earlier post but I posted more info in the comments below with HeadLoss and GPM measurements of my system.
Can you please advise if those look correct? I also had some questions.

Again, I really appreciate your answers and time.

Comment: Here are some photos of my system if this helps. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3tJmysSYpbCR0huQXRZcGcwczA

Answer (score 2):

One possibility (and it's just that - a possibility, a guess, not definitive) is that your system leaks, and makeup water is being constantly introduced by an automatic fill valve.

The problem with that is that new water comes with oxygen dissolved in it, and oxygen rusts cast iron. So if your pump plugs up with rust, and fails, that might be your cause - as you have not provided any information on the symptoms of failure or state of the failed pumps, it remains a guess. If the failures are normally at the start of heating season, that's another clue in this direction - lots of time for the pump to rust while not spinning all summer.

If that is the case, a stainless steel pump might be the solution to your problem, though another solution would be to stop the leaks.

Systems with cast iron pumps and no leaks just rust out the oxygen that's in the initial fill water, and then rust no more, as there's no more oxygen.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. There is shut-off valve that used to leak and even the zone-valves used to leak but not anymore. Luckily Armstrong sent me replacement for the pump. However, for the time being I had the older spare one which is now installed. But even this pump is making a grinding noise. Actually this was the original pump that was replaced by new maintenance free one (S-25 MF/BF) which went bad.  I have taken some pictures and made the audio recording of the noise. I don't know if this can be helpful in diagnosing the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Here is the audio. SE did not let me post it. http://www.filedropper.com/201612050031

Comment: Here are links to photos in case SE decided not to display those. http://www.filedropper.com/1_218 http://www.filedropper.com/2_197  http://www.filedropper.com/3_108 http://www.filedropper.com/4_64 http://www.filedropper.com/5_40 http://www.filedropper.com/6_32

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your pump has nothing to do with new water being introduced into your heating system. Any new water never touches the coupler or that part of the pump and NO you do not need a stainless or bronze pump, as mentioned elsewhere. However, Your Armstrong pump does need lubricated yearly. You need to remove the cap on the oil tube and add a few drops of special pump oil sold by a pump dealer. And make sure you only buy a genuine armstrong pump, not an after market piece of crap. Some motors have the oil tubes and some do not; look closely. But that is not why the coupler needs replaced so often. The problem with coupler breakage is usually that the rubber motor mounts become worn or soft and allow the motor to sag down in the motor mount. This sagging allows the motor and pump shaft to run out of line, and will cause excess wear. You could take the motor to a repair shop and have them repair the motor or just replace the motor and/or bearing assembly. This pump and the Bell and Gossett series 100 pumps are what we call "BULLIT-PROOF" since they last so long and are almost trouble free. (both of these pumps look almost identical). If you want to replace the pump with a "wet rotor close coupled" pump, make sure you buy one that has the same characteristics as this pump. (head and flow). A larger pump can introduce noise into your heating system.

Comment: Have a good knowledge of the subject you are writing about. The pump mentioned is not a wet rotor pump so the new water introduced into the system will not come in contact with the coupler.

Comment: Water need not touch the coupler at all for the  coupler to break. If the wet parts are frozen in place by rust, and the motor starts, the coupler breaks.  And the wet parts can definitely be frozen in place by rust if there is a leak, seen it many times.

Comment: So I ask; why was my answer downgraded. Does someone think my answer is not accurate. If so , please comment and tell me why, since I probably have the most accurate answer.

Comment: On a i/12hp. pump, the motor isn't strong enough to break the coupler since the motor is split phase and not a capacitor start. Larger pump motors may break the coupler.depending on the coupler used.

Comment: Thanks everyone for you response. I really appreciate it as I am learning a lot through this ordeal about HVAC systems. So as I said last year I had replaced my circulator with 
lubrication (maintenance) free model for Armstrong S-25 MF, 174031MF-013 to be exact and after running for over 3/4 months it broke. Since this was under warrant Armstrong 
sent me a new one and now it's in operation. It's been running only for about 1 month or so. It hasn't gotten that cold yet.It's been running only for about 1 month or so. It hasn't gotten that cold yet.  Cont. in next comment...

Comment: But from past incidents circulator breaks every time it gets very cold and pump has to probably continuously run for 2-3 days. One thing I didn't mention is that my boiler is about 30 years old 
and loos a bit rusty but it's been working. Recently I had to replace gas valve for autopilot and zone valves for two of the zones because the motor was making crackling noise 
and I got it replaced before it went bad. I used to different guys to for zone values and gas valve.  Cont. in next comment...

Comment: When I explained to both of them my situation, they immediately said I need to replace the whole system and each gave me their price (4-5k). 
While I do want to get a new boiler, I also tried to explain that it's not the boiler that breaks while 
I admit it is old but it's the pump that goes bad. They both told me this is very powerful and that it shouldn't break. They will use same or similar pump in the new installation.  Cont. in next comment...

Comment: I do want to replace the boiler but I also don't want to just blindly use the same/similar so I went ahead and started doing some of my own research about HeadLoss/GMP etc. 
I came across this youtbe video series, https://youtu.be/h8r-qLPXFBg (parts 1-6) and measured around my house. 
Here are my calculations, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3tJmysSYpbCZnZkLUpDdGFxdTA/view and here is PDF on Performance chart for S-25. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3tJmysSYpbCTlY5SkR4LVdjS0U/view .Cont. in next comment...

Comment: From my calucations based on those youtube video, I think HeadLoss is an issue here since max HeadLoss for S-25 is about 8ft. So I decided that with my new boiler I would want to use a separate circulator for each zone, Grundfos Alpha2 or similar model from Taco, 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3tJmysSYpbCR3dYTU96X3oxelE/view.  However, I stumbpled upon this document, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3tJmysSYpbCX0pTSVY2dzhkRm8/view, which basically says Head Feet (HL) is not an in issue in a closed
system what you need to worry about is Frication Head. Cont. in next comment...

Comment: It also says that you only need to cacluate the longest run of pipes in a multizone system and then add 50% to it. Then use that number for Head when 
buying a pump. Based on the videos HL = Total Development Length (i.e. length of all copper pipes for each zone) * 1.5 * 0.04.  

I am consfused. 

Any help would be appreciated.